# How can I let server execute Rails command before Apache boots?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apache

When the server reboots, it automatically starts, Apache, MySQL(server), vsftpd, and etc.

But my application won't work right until I execute this command below

```
bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start RAILS_ENV=production
```

It's due to usage of `Sunspot Solr gem`.

So, every time I reboot server, I have to stop Apache first, and type the command written above, then I start Apache again.

Is it possible to let server do it automatically?

Comment: why are you using a solr installation meant for development, in production?

Comment: You can use gem 'foreman'

Comment: @sevenseacat what do you mean by saying that?can't I use solr in production? But it's working though

Comment: @rhernando Thanks for telling awesome gem. But I noticed that it works only when after Apache launched.So should I insert 3 lines to execute, `stop apache`, `start solr`, and `start apache` here?